# Button Style is not applying XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have been learning WPF for a little while now and I am starting to use styles to make my forms look a little better.

The issue I am running into is for some reason my button style will not be applied anywhere. I am pretty sure I am overwriting the default button style. All of my other styles are working just fine I just can't figure this one out. Here is my code.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Employee_Time_Entry">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Texts.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- Regular button -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundOrangeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundLightBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSizeLarge}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource LatoRegular}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50 10" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        CornerRadius="10"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the form code where the button will not apply the style.

```
<Page x:Class="Employee_Time_Entry.Views.Login"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Employee_Time_Entry"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
  Title="Login">

<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Backgrounds/BlueWaveBackground.jpg"/>
    </Border.Background>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" >
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ForegroundLightBrush}" 
                        CornerRadius="10" 
                        Padding="15 10 15 15" 
                        Width="250" 
                        Margin="50 50 50 0">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sign In" Padding="0 0 0 10" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoBold}"/>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 10 5 0" Text="User Name:" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBox}"/>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 15 5 0" Text="Password:" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBox}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBox/>
                                    <PasswordBox/>
                                    <Button Content="Login" 
                                            Margin = "10 10"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

[Here is a picture of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m5xe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the resource file is referenced either application wide or within the page you want to apply it.

To apply the resources from the file to a specific page, you need to add it to the page resources.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assembly.Namespace;component/MyResourceFileName.xaml"
                                x:Name="Dict" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

To apply the resource to your entire application, you would do the same but to your app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assembly.Namespace;component/MyResourceFileName.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

It should be noted that your button style will not display any content. Your style only has a Border which cannot display content. Make sure you add a ContentPresenter inside of the Button

Comment: Ah! So obvious once you said it. Thank you so much it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the style to your button, Like this

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource /the name of your style here/}" Content="Login" Margin = "10 10"/>
```

On your button style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="/nameyourstyle/" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
```

.....